# Administrator password was not updated in the database error in configuring ATG version 11.0.0 integrated with Endeca

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I'm facing an error while configuring the `ATG 11.0.0` with `Oracle DB` and with `Endeca 11.0.0`.

Here is the error:

> Importing ( 8 of 8 ) /CIM/tmp/import/switchingA-import4.xml:
>   /CommerceReferenceStore/Store/Storefront/data/storecontent.xml to /atg/store/
>   stores/StoreContentRepository
>   /CommerceReferenceStore/Store/KnowledgeBase/install/data/basic-urls.xml to /
>   atg/multisite/SiteRepository
>   ...Success

Update:

administrator password (1 of 1). The administrator password was not
updated in the database. The update was bypassed. Please check the cim.log for
details

```
-------DATA IMPORT FAILED-------------------------------------------------------

enter [h]Help, [m]Main Menu, [q]Quit to exit


Make sure you have configured the connection details and created the schema.

1 of 8 data imports had errors. Please check D:\E2E\ATG\ATG11.0\CIM\log/
cim.log for more details.


 *[D]  Done - Mark Import as Done
  [C]  Continue
```

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

It may be because the schema is corrupted..

Drop the production,`CAT_A` and `CAT_B` schemas and do the steps on

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, such that I couldn't login to the dynamo admin servers on bcc and prod instances.  I modified the unpacked ear file to start up with Admin.Reset, which resets it to admin/admin and it works.

Comment: I really don't your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Which file? And in which ear publishing or production? What changes  did you make to the file?

Comment: FYI, this error always occurs to me when I am configuring **ATG Platform 11.0.0** with **Endeca** through **CIM.bat**